# How can I resize images in subfolders with these conditions?

Tags: bash, shell-script, ubuntu, imagemagick

Let's say I have a folder with many subfolders in it. Each of these subfolders contain many images.

I want to resize these images in each subfolders with the following conditions:

- If the image's height is less than 1000 pixels, then do noting.
- If the image's hieght is between 1001 to 2500 pixels, then resize it down to 70%.
- If the image's hieght is between 2501 to 3000 pixels, then resize it down to 50%.
- If the image's hieght is more than 3000 pixels, then resize it down to 30%.
- the new images replaces the old ones.

Normally I can do this with a few images, by looking at image's information one-by-one and using mogrify command, but this time I have too many subfolders. Since I'm a new linux user, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I modified the code that [jajo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/429930/how-can-i-resize-images-in-subfolders-with-these-conditions/429942#429942) provided and got it working this way:

```
MIN_RES=1001
MAX_RES=2500
RES11=2501
RES12=3000
RES21=3001
RES22=10000

    for i in *.jpg; do
YRES=$(identify -verbose $i|grep Geometry: |cut -d 'x' -f2 |sed 's|+.*||g')
if [ $YRES -gt $MIN_RES ] && [ $YRES -lt $MAX_RES ]; then

echo "Found: $i with y-res: $YRES";

# convert
convert -resize 70% $i $i;

elif [ $YRES -gt $RES11 ] && [ $YRES -lt $RES12 ]; then

echo "Found: $i with y-res: $YRES";

convert -resize 50% $i $i;

else [ $YRES -gt $RES21 ] && [ $YRES -lt $RES22 ]

echo "Found: $i with y-res: $YRES";

convert -resize 30% $i $i;

fi
done
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/234970)

Comment: @peterh, note that they claim to be the OP, so [merging their accounts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) would be a more appropriate course of action.

Comment: peterh's advice still holds; if you have an answer for the current question, accept it and then ask a separate question for any major differences.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find here : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1164/how-to-easily-resize-images-via-command-line some details on command-line tools offered by ImageMagick.

So, to perform the job on a single picture, I would :

- use identify tool to read metadata of pictures, for example:

  $ identify /tmp/p1.jpg
  /tmp/p1.jpg JPEG 1487x925 1487x925+0+0 8-bit sRGB 314106B 0.000u 0:00.000
- interpret output tou extract dimensions 1487x925
- apply my rules to build a convert command.

A loop based on " find " command results would allow to repeat this for one or more folders.

Answer (score 0):

you can use from ImageMagic toolbox "identify" for reading image resolution and "convert" for converting images. Something like this:

```
MIN_RES=100
MAX_RES=500
for i in *.jpg; do
    YRES=$(identify -verbose $i|grep Geometry: |cut -d 'x' -f2 |sed 's|+.*||g')
    if [ $YRES -gt $MIN_RES ] && [ $YRES -lt $MAX_RES ]; then

        echo "Found: $i with y-res: $YRES";

        # convert
        convert -resize 50% $i $i;

    fi
done
```